# Android Flip Animation - No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android

As i followed this tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html , and literally copy and pasted anim code from there, i got this errors https://i.stack.imgur.com/li1bB.jpg . Been trying to find solution for about an hour, but eventually I gave up. Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define values for those missing integers in your integers.xml file.

If you don't have one already then you will need to create it at:

`res/values/integers.xml`

It would look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="card_flip_time_full">500</integer>
    <integer name="card_flip_time_half">250</integer>
</resources>
```